# Akka won't override application.conf with command line parameters

Tags: scala, akka, scala-2.10

I thought since akka 2.1.4 uses typesafe config, it would just override whatever -D parameter I throw at it via command line, like play framework does. Turns out it doesn't seem to work that way. Just adding a `-Dakka.remote.netty.port=2552` doesn't really change anything when added in to the commandline. Do I have to enable anything to make overrides work?

Additional info: I tried using the -D parameters in the Intellij launcher and with `java -cp app.jar -Dakka.remote.netty.port=2552` after doing an `sbt assembly`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alright, I found out what I was doing wrong. It seems that overrides do not work when only a section of the `application.conf` is loaded. You cannot override the netty port with `-Dakka.remote.netty.port=2553` when you configure your actor system by ***only loading a specific section*** from the application.conf like this:

```
val system = ActorSystem("myActorSystem",ConfigFactory.load.getConfig("client"))
```

application.conf file:

```
client{
  akka {

  log-config-on-start = on
   loglevel = "INFO"
   actor {
      provider = "akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider"
      include "serialization.conf"
   }

   remote {
    transport = "akka.remote.netty.NettyRemoteTransport"
    netty {
      hostname = "127.0.0.1"
      port = 2552
    }
    log-sent-messages = off
    log-received-messages = off
   }
  }
}
```

In this case, although you specify "client" as a subsection to load, you will still have to prepend "client" as a key to your values that will override them by using command line parameters.

Please note though, that the values in the config file will not be prepended by "client" when being loaded that way. So by using `-Dclient.akka.remote.netty.port=2553` you can effectively override as you are used to.

Comment: "You cannot override the netty port with ... by only loading a specific section". Nothing wrong here. After you add `client` to conf file you should also add it to java option. So instead of Dakka.remote.netty.port=2553 you should try -D**client**.akka.remote.netty.port=2553`.

Comment: if some env define, it also can be specified in command: for example:`port = ${?PORT}`  command: `-DPORT=8081`

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this same issue. I was using 'java -jar project.jar -Dblah=whatever' to run the project which was not overriding the conf file. But, 'java -jar -Dblah=whatever project.jar' did override the conf file.

Comment: This is because you want to add the parameter "-Dblah=whatever" as VM options not program arguments. Before the jar file is VM options. After they are program arguments. See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html.